# Android json parsing error

Tags: android, json

My json data is given below:

```
[
  {"Category_Id":"C1 ","Category_Name":"breakfast"},
  {"Category_Id":"C2 ","Category_Name":"appetizers & snacks"},
  {"Category_Id":"C3 ","Category_Name":"sandwiches & more"},
  {"Category_Id":"C4 ","Category_Name":"burgers & wraps"},
  {"Category_Id":"C5 ","Category_Name":"salads"},
  {"Category_Id":"C6 ","Category_Name":"soup"},
  {"Category_Id":"C7 ","Category_Name":"pizza & pasta"},
  {"Category_Id":"C8 ","Category_Name":"kids menu"},
  {"Category_Id":"C9 ","Category_Name":"main dishes"},
  {"Category_Id":"C10 ","Category_Name":"oriental cuisine"},
  {"Category_Id":"C11 ","Category_Name":"desserts"},
  {"Category_Id":"C12 ","Category_Name":"shakes & smoothies"},
  {"Category_Id":"C13 ","Category_Name":"drinks"},
  {"Category_Id":"C14","Category_Name":"333"}
]
```

how could i parse these data and set the text in button dynamically.

Comment: how much you tried?. post the code.

Comment: In this case you are having a JSONArray, so you have to parse this string into JSONArray (Not JSONObject ). Then start parsing from the JSONArray.... Well, i have written the whole code below in my answer, you can see. Hope it helped you

Comment: Can you post your code where you are parsing json

Comment: Thanks  Rahat Raina. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str ="[{\"Category_Id\":\"C1 \",\"Category_Name\":\"breakfast\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C2 \",\"Category_Name\":\"appetizers & snacks\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C3 \",\"Category_Name\":\"sandwiches & more\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C4 \",\"Category_Name\":\"burgers & wraps\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C5 \",\"Category_Name\":\"salads\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C6 \",\"Category_Name\":\"soup\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C7 \",\"Category_Name\":\"pizza & pasta\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C8 \",\"Category_Name\":\"kids menu\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C9 \",\"Category_Name\":\"main dishes\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C10 \",\"Category_Name\":\"oriental cuisine\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C11 \",\"Category_Name\":\"desserts\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C12 \",\"Category_Name\":\"shakes & smoothies\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C13 \",\"Category_Name\":\"drinks\"},{\"Category_Id\":\"C14\",\"Category_Name\":\"333\"}]";
        JSONArray jarray;
        try{
            jarray = new JSONArray("");
            for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
            {
                String id = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Category_Id");
                String name = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Category_Name");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get json parser error just check whether your json string is correct or not by checking it in online in any json parsing website like:-

http://jsonlint.com/

OR

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: After checking if your getting json parser error means problem is at your End.

Comment: The  json String is correct, but the JSON is in Array format, so you have to parse it in the JSONArray, not the JSONObject. That might be the issue for him

Comment: Ya, if possible change JSON array to JSON object, by adding the JSON array to any object means in {...}

Answer (score 0):

For this all you need to do is a for loop to go through the Json response. Something like this should do the trick.

```
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    try{
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(myJsonResponse);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {

JsonObject object = new JsonObject(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i));
            buttonTextString = object.getString("Category_Name);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `JSONArray` before then parse `JSONObject` to parse each element on your json data. And final `setText` for button each element you can parse